“Difficulty Accessing Redesigned Website from Local Network - How to Resolve 404 Error
Description:
I recently redesigned our website and migrated it from Namecheap hosting to Hostinger. While the updated design is accessible from external networks when hosted on Namecheap, I’m encountering a persistent 404 error when attempting to access it from our local network after migrating to Hostinger.
Issue Details:
•   The redesigned website was previously hosted on Namecheap without any issues.
•   After migrating to Hostinger, the website is accessible without any problems from external networks, confirmed through multiple devices and locations.
•   However, when attempting to access the website from our local network, we consistently receive a 404 error.
•   Troubleshooting steps undertaken so far:
•   Cleared cache on devices within the local network.
•   Checked router settings and firewall configurations, ensuring they allow access to the new website.
•   Tested access from different devices within the local network, all resulting in the same 404 error.
•   Verified DNS configuration and ensured that it correctly points to Hostinger’s IP address ([IP address]).
•   Contacted our ISP and both Namecheap and Hostinger support teams for assistance, but the issue persists.
•   Reviewed proxy settings and confirmed that they are not causing the issue.

Request for Assistance:
We are seeking guidance on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
